# Obj-C Accessors and ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, accessor

I wrote a *very* basic class to play with the new ARC and accessor methods, just to get a feel for how they work. From what I've read, the ARC should replace manual reference counting, right? But I get a problem with my accessor methods.

Here's my Interface/Implementation for my `Container` class:

```
// interface
@interface Container : NSObject {
   NSMutableString *string;
}

- (NSMutableString *)string;
- (void)setString:(NSMutableString *)aString;

@end

// implementation
@implementation Container

- (NSMutableString *)string
{
   return string;
}

- (void)setString:(NSMutableString *)aString
{
   string = aString;
}

- (NSString *)description
{
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"inner string = %@", string];
}

@end
```

It seems alright to me, all the reference counting details are handled by the ARC I believe. The problem occurs in the main method:

```
Container *myContainer = [[Container alloc] init];
  NSMutableString *aString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello!"];

[myContainer setString:aString];

NSLog(@"%@", myContainer);

[aString setString:@"Bye!"];

NSLog(@"%@", myContainer);

aString = [myContainer string];
[aString setString:@"Bye, again!"];

NSLog(@"%@", myContainer);
```

It seems that `aString` points to the `string` member variable, which means when I change `aString` I also change `string` with it. I tried releasing `aString` from the `main()` method but then I get a compiler error. How do I fix this? Do I use the `copy` method, or is there another way?

Comment: Variables under ARC environment will be created with a `strong` reference. If you need to copy a value stored in a pointer (as it seems to be the case above), you have explicitly declare your property as copy or create a setter method that copies the value stored in your variable (this has always been the case and ARC doesn't/shouldn't affect it).

Comment: So I should write this: `string = [aString copy]`? That'll fix the problem right?

Comment: You don't call `release/retain/dealloc` under ARC, let the compiler do it for you.

Comment: Interestingly `[aString copy]` will return an immutable `NSString`. You would probably want to use `[aString mutableCopy]`.

Answer (score 0):

rcplusplus,

You asked:

> It seems that aString points to the string member variable, which means when I change aString I also change string with it. I tried releasing aString from the main() method but then I get a compiler error. How do I fix this? Do I use the copy method, or is there another way?

The way to release any ARC item is to set it to `nil`. This tells the compiler you are through with this item. It is released in the assignment.

Example:

```
[myContainer setString: nil];
myContainer.string = nil;
```

or, from within your class:

```
string = nil;
```

Andrew